# How should I specify seasonality in CausalImpact?

Tags: time-series, python, intervention-analysis, causalimpact

I am working with the Python implementation of Google's CausalImpact package. My data is at daily frequency (365 observations per year); however, to inspect the effect of intervention, my pre-period is approximately 5 months long, and my post-period is approximately 5 months long. My full-range data (longer about 3 years) clearly shows yearly seasonality.

My question: how do I set the model up for yearly seasonality?

`dated_data = df`

`pre_period = ['2018-01-01', '2018-06-05']   # Prior to known event`

`post_period = ['2018-06-06', '2019-11-25']  # After first, before second event`

`ci = CausalImpact(dated_data, pre_period, post_period,
                   prior_level_sd=None,
                   niter=1000,
                   nseasons=[{'period': ???}],
                   seasonal_duration=???)'`

Any advice would be most welcomed.

Comment: Hi @nellac77, if you want please post python questions on the github issues thread: https://github.com/dafiti/causalimpact/issues